# Return specific Matrix row?

Tags: matrix

I'm looking to be able to return the info from a field(s) from a Matrix row where I know which row I want (long story). I had a guess at various ways of doing this, but in the end the only way that worked was to run the loop with an if statement to limit the output to a given row's id, e.g:

```
{% for block in entry.bodyRepeater %}
    {% if loop.index==2 %}
    <h3>{{ block.heading }}</h3>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Guessing there might be a better way though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works but using this code can be a problem if you are dealing with a huge number of rows.

To access the n-th row, you can use:

```
{{ entry.blockRepeater.findElementAtOffset(n-1).heading }}
```

I found this method in the `ElementCriteriaModel` class. You can test if a certain row exists using `entry.blockRepeater.offsetExists(n)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
{% set block = entry.bodyRepeater.nth(2) %}

{% if block %}
    <h3>{{ block.heading }}</h3>
{% endif %}
```

Craft 2.2 introduced the [`nth`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#nth) method to ElementCriteriaModel objects for fetching the element at a specific offset.
It's more convienient to use this instead of a combination of the undocumented `offsetExists` and `findElementAtOffset` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this for a quiz, getting the row from the url

```
{% set theRow = craft.request.getParam('row') %} 
{{entry.matrixField[theRow].body}}
```

Just remember zero is the first row.

Comment: `entry.matrixField[1]` queries for all the blocks, so it isn't a whole lot more efficient then the loop approach in the question.